# AsyncValidation with ngrx

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-validation

I have the following form that I would like to validate from a value in the ngrx store

```
this.form = new FormGroup({
     serviceNr: new FormControl('', {
        validators: [Validators.required],
     }, [this.doubleServiceNrAsyncValidator()]),
     ...
});
```

I made sure my validator is finite, as per Angular docs

```
ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.isDestroyed.next(true);
    this.isDestroyed.complete();
}
```

in my template

```
<mat-error *ngIf="form.get('serviceNr').hasError('existingNr')">
        {{ 'GENERAL.ALERTS.ERROR.RESOURCE_ALREADY_EXIST' | translate : { number: this.form.get('serviceNr').value } }}
 </mat-error>
```

and my validate function looks like this:

```
doubleServiceNrAsyncValidator = () => (_) => this.store.pipe(select(selectError)).pipe(
    takeUntil(this.isDestroyed),
    map(err => {
      if (err?.errorCode === ErrorCodeEnum.RESOURCE_ALREADY_EXIST) {
        return { existingNr: true };
      }
      if (!!err) {
        return { unknown: true };
      }
      return null;
    }),
)
```

The async validator is being called, and it returns `{ existingNr: true }` fine. But the field is not being marked as `invalid`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour is caused by the fact that your
`this.store.pipe(select(selectError))` observable never completes, which leads the form control which is associated with the validation to be in a `PENDING` state. While the `formControl` is in such state no changes will be applied to it's `valid` property.

The quick fix is to use either `take(1)` or `first()` inside your validator like so:

```js
doubleServiceNrAsyncValidator = () => (_) => this.store.pipe(select(selectError)).pipe(
    first(),
    map(err => {
      if (err?.errorCode === ErrorCodeEnum.RESOURCE_ALREADY_EXIST) {
        return { existingNr: true };
      }
      if (!!err) {
        return { unknown: true };
      }
      return null;
    }),
```

The `first` opertor will complete the source stream, which will cause the formControl to apply all necesary changes to the `valid` field

In the following [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-rgb-fewl1?file=/src/app/app.component.ts) i have created a side by side example, which you and anyone in the future might find usefull, because this is one of the cases that you usualy dont find in the docs :D

Comment: You were right. I thought `takeUntil` would do the job. I had to filter for only defined err objects in the store before calling `first()`. Thanks man